# C# Making picturebox display on custom form

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I am having some issues with regards to making a picturebox display.

I am working on a simple RPG type game (a prototype), and the player can make a character.  The character class has a picturebox attached to it, and when they create a character, an image is selected for this picturebox.

Once the game starts, the character spawns on a location.  However, the picturebox doesn't show.  Whilst on a location, the character can move around.  After a random number of steps, combat is initiated, and the combat screen loads.  Even though the picturebox doesn't load, the character seems to move around, and combat does get initiated.

When I leave combat and return to the form, the picturebox for the character appears.  I have other pictureboxes on the location form, and they load.

The constructor for a location has a call to a method called initialise. Here is some relevant code from this method:

```
 public void Initialise()
    {                    
        c = StateManager.C;
        StepCount = 0;
        SetStepsTillCombat();
        EntranceLocation = "";
        SetStartPosition();
        c.Pic.Location = NewLocation ;//c.Pic is the picturebox            
        this.Controls.Add(c.Pic);
```

The set start position method aims to determine where the player should spawn.  The code for this is as follows:

```
public void SetStartPosition()
    {
        switch (EntranceLocation)
        {
            case "North":
                StartLocation.X = this.Width/2;
                StartLocation.Y=10;
                NewLocation = StartLocation;
                break;
            case "South":
                StartLocation.X = this.Width/2;
                StartLocation.Y=this.Height - c.Pic.Height;
                NewLocation = StartLocation;
                break;
            case "West":
                StartLocation.X = 10;
                StartLocation.Y=this.Height/2;
                NewLocation = StartLocation;
                break;
            case "East":
                StartLocation.X = this.Width-c.Pic.Height;
                StartLocation.Y=this.Height/2;
                NewLocation = StartLocation;
                break;
            case "":
                StartLocation.X = this.Width / 2;
                StartLocation.Y = this.Height / 2;
                NewLocation = StartLocation;
                break;

        }

    }
```

I can't remember why I am even using startlocation, instead of setting newlocation directly, there was a reason, and then I removed the feature.  Anyway, depending on where the player enters the location, their spawn point will differ, or if the player enters the first location when starting the game, they start at a set point.  I call this method first, before assigning the location of the player picturebox.

When first entering a location, there is no picture.  When I leave combat, I have the following code:

```
        public void EndClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        c.NumberOfBattles++;
        returnLocation.Spawn(c.Location);//Coordinates for where to spawn the player
        returnLocation.SetStepsTillCombat();
        returnLocation.StepCount = 0;
        returnLocation.Show();//Load the location I entered combat from
    }
```

The spawn method looks like:

```
public void Spawn(Point p)
    {
        c.Location = p;
        c.Pic.Location = c.Location;
        this.Controls.Add(c.Pic);
    }
```

When doing this, c.Pic does display.

I can't see what I am doing wrong here, any input would be appreciated.  I think I have included all relevant code.

EDIT:

I found a work around, whereby each time I move the character, I call the spawn method, though this seems like an inefficient way to do things.

Comment: Well, why not ask the debugger??? He will know, if not the purpose, the at least the value of `NewLocation`..

Comment: I have.  New location is set to what it should be.

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Could it be covered? (Use BringToFront) or emtpy? (Set a BackColor or a Border to test!)

Comment: Tried that, still doing it.  I added a call to the spawn method each time I move, and when I press move, it appears.  I tried modifying it so that when the form loads, it called spawn, but nothing.